# ReactJS - change class of component from another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Very new to React, and coming from a jQuery background, the first thing I want to be able to do is toggle classes.

I understand how I can toggle a class within the same react component like this:

```
class ButtonParent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {    
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      condition: false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }
  handleClick() {
    this.setState({
      condition: !this.state.condition
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ButtonChild        
        className={ this.state.condition ? "button toggled" : "button" }
        toggleClassName={ this.handleClick }
      >
        Click me if you dare!
      </ButtonChild>
    )
  }
}

class ButtonChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={ this.props.className }
        onClick={ this.props.toggleClassName }
      >
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    )    
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<ButtonParent />, document.getElementById('app'))
```

But what if I have a a separate component that I want to use in order to toggle the class of the  component? Is there no easy way to do this in React?

Thanks!

Comment: Depends where the components are located in relation each other, please add your specific use case e.g. could be located anywhere in app, changing child from parent or vice versa, how many components sit between them.

Comment: @Dominic Let's say it can be located anywhere in the app.

Comment: @BestDevTutorials In the case that the component that will toggle the state of "ButtonParent" component is located anywhere in the app, then your best bet is to use a Context that wraps your whole app and its components (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) or use Redux

Comment: So if you want a component action to effect a sibling, you have to hoist the classname prop all the way up to a common parent. Things like flux or redux are state management tools to help avoid that, I would recommend looking into one of those.

Comment: Are these really the solutions? I've never been so turned-off from using a library until I started with React

Answer (score -2):

Just create an ButtonChild.js file near your ButtonParent.js file and export your component

```
export default class ButtonChild extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className={ this.props.className }
        onClick={ this.props.toggleClassName }
      >
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    )    
  }
}
```

Import it in you ButtonParent.js file like this

```
import ButtonChild from './ButtonParent.js'
```